# Limit of a fraction involving multiple square roots

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, radicals, limits-without-lhopital

$$\lim_{x\to2}{\frac{\sqrt{3x-2}-\sqrt{5x-6}}{\sqrt{2x-1}-\sqrt{x+1}}}$$

Evaluate the limit.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\to2}{\frac{\sqrt{3x-2}-\sqrt{5x-6}}{\sqrt{2x-1}-\sqrt{x+1}}}=\lim_{x\to2}{\frac{(3x-2-(5x-6))(\sqrt{2x-1}+\sqrt{x+1})}{(2x-1-(x+1))(\sqrt{3x-2}+\sqrt{5x-6})}}=$$
$$=-2\cdot\frac{\sqrt3+\sqrt3}{2+2}=-\sqrt3$$

Comment: Could you possibly explain where the second limit expression comes from? I cant spot how its equivalent.

Comment: @user3486373 I used $(a-b)(a+b)=a^2-b^2$ and $\frac{ac}{bc}=\frac{a}{b}.$ For example $(\sqrt{3x-2}-\sqrt{5x-6})(\sqrt{3x-2}+\sqrt{5x-6})=3x-2-(5x-6)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You did that faster than I could read it :)

Answer (score 2):

That stinks a lot as homework. A general hint for solving such a problem is to "rationalize" both numerator and denominator i.e. multiply the whole thing by

$$\frac{\sqrt{3x-2}+\sqrt{5x-6}}{\sqrt{3x-2}+\sqrt{5x-6}}\cdot \frac{\sqrt{2x-1}+\sqrt{x+1}}{\sqrt{2x-1}+\sqrt{x+1}}$$

Comment: This was attempted but did not produce anything close to being able to be calculated. Also I have looked everywhere online and not found any example of calculating any limits in this form so I thought as a last resort I'd ask on this website.

Comment: Could you please write your attempt so we can tell you how to proceed? I computed it with the hint I gave you.. It works..

Comment: I'm not sure the expression you've written is equivalent

Comment: I wrote $1$. I'm not sure you read the sentence that precedes it.

Comment: yeah thats right i didnt oops, sorry about that. i'll give it a try now

Comment: "*rationalize both numerator and denominator*" You only need to rationalize the denominator. In fact, it's not possible to rationalize both simultaneously, otherwise plugging in $x=3$ gives a contradiction (original expression gives an irrational number, both being rationalized give a rational number). However, I know what you meant --- perform the operation of multiplying by the conjugate of the denominator to both the numerator and denominator.

Comment: Ok well that would explain why i struggled then. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Set $x-2=h$

and rationalize the denominator & the numerator.

Setting limit to $0$ often eases of the calculation

Comment: Doing this still gives you a limit of 0/0 so im not sure its too useful in this example but i'll keep it in mind in future, thanks!